# ImageMagick - how to resize and position

Tags: imagemagick

I want to do the following using ImageMagick (linux command line): resize image A to 125% of it's size, and then place it overtop a larger image B - at B's center, but with an offset of 175px to the right

The following doesn't work for me, and from what I'm reading, it should:

```
    composite -gravity center -geometry '125%+175+0' <imageA_path> <imageB_path> <output_file_path>
```

I also tried this with no luck:

```
    convert <imageA_path> -resize 125% | composite -gravity center -geometry +175+0 - <imageB_path> <output_file_path>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I resolved the problem by using convert to create a temporary image (enlarged), then composite to place the image on the larger one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the resize command, you will need to specify and input image and an output image. You will also need to specify the input image on the composite command.

```
    convert <imageA_path> -resize 125% <resized_imageA_path> | composite -gravity center -geometry +175+0 <resized_imageA_path> <imageB_path> <output_file_path>
```

You can have the  as the same as , but this will overwrite the original imageA with the resized version.

If you specify a new image path/name then it will save the resize as a new image. If you don't want to keep these images then you could specify a directory where you could easily delete all of the images created in there.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Never mind, I just saw your comment.

Comment: Thanks. You answered the question, so I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the answer from Moogle you can solve your problem with those two commands - but with usign `-` you'll get the full power of piping.

```
convert <imageA_path> -resize 125% - | composite -gravity center -geometry +175+0 - <imageB_path> <output_image_path>
```

should do it without intermediate files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single command line using a stack

```
composite -gravity center -geometry +175+0 \( -resize 125% <imageA_path> \) <imageB_path> <output_file_path>
```

The operations in the parenthesis run first and the result is used in place of a file.  Make sure you have white space around the `\(` and `\)` delimiters or you will get a parse error.